# SQL Deduplication, populating the duplicates with its unique identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to be able to populate any duplicate items in a table with its unique identifier. So for example, in the table below;

PROJ00002492 should get a GlobalFamilDupID of PROJ00002492 (itself, aka the ControlNumber column), and all other duplicates should get the same value PROJ00002492.

PROJ00005876 should get the value PROJ00005876 (aka itself, the ControlNumber column).

[image]

Code:

```
update mstr
    SET 
        IsGlobalFamilyUnique = case when (rn > 1) then 0 else 1 end
    from(
    select
        ControlNumber,
        MD5hash,
        IsglobalFamilyUnique,
        GlobalFamilyDupID,
        row_number() over (partition by [MD5Hash] order by ID asc) [RN]
    from dbo.tblMaster
    where NuixGuid = TopLvlGuid and IsGlobalFamilyUnique is null
)mstr
```

The above code works, but I can't think how to populate the GlobalFamilDupID column? Will I have to do it in a separate query?

Comment: What errors or issues are you experiencing when attempting this?

Comment: No errors, my code works so far, I just can't think how to populate the GlobalFamilyDupID column based on my question

Comment: You could put a cte at  the beginning with all ControlNumber and MD5Hash records with RN = 1 and join it to the table within your update statement...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add the value you need into your SELECT using

```
FIRST_VALUE(ControlNumber) over (partition by [MD5Hash] order by ID
```

Then use the value in your UPDATE